# How to show a new Button after Button was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, decision-tree

Here is my problem. I want to create a questionnaire.

How are you? A)Button "Good" B)Button "Bad"

i.e. user click button B.)

Alert Window is shown and notifying user about his/her last choice. 
New Question and Buttons appear on the same page. Essentially, users will go through the set of questions on the same page.

Why are you Bad? A)Button "Some Txt" B.)Button "Some Txt"

How can I show new question and new buttons on the same page. The concept should follow some kind of decision tree logic.

Solutions, advises or "where-to-check hints" appreciated. Please, help me!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hello</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function buttonclickgood() {
        alert('you have clicked Good');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function buttonclickbad() {
        alert('you have clicked Bad');
    }
</script>

</head>
<p>How are you?</p>
<input type="button" value="Good!" onclick="buttonclickgood()"/> 
<input type="button" value="Bad!" onclick="buttonclickbad()"/> 

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In my opinion it is necessary to initialize an array that contains all of them can answer your questions.
Then we must make a function that will update the buttons depending on the issue or you is you. Then, in the recovery of onclick of your buttons, you must make an alert that recovers the value of your buttons to display in the alert.
Then the question of the conservation of selected data, you need a different array that allows you to store the chosen answer.

Comment: you dont need to show a new button or anythng like that . you can just play it using javascript .... see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You might want to explore JQuery a bit.

Particularly something around the .click() API 
https://api.jquery.com/click/

Are you intending to do this just on the client side? I would recommend doing this through a client/server model thou e.g. Angular(Client) -> NodeJS(Server)

That is, having the question generation logic in node and let the client consume the questions however it is not impossible to do everything on the client.

So you code will be something like

```
<script src="../script/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    <!-- maybe let say define your data (questions) here -->
    var data = 
      [ 
          {
             <!--example ... --> 
          }
      ] 
    $("#btn_1").click(function() {
          <!-- do some logic with the data above. Process it then print the new question by update your text -->
          $('#TxtArea').val(data); 
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some javascript to hide/show your different steps. With JQuery for example you can do something like that:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".step").hide();
            $(".step-1").show();
        });

        function buttonclick(nextStep)
        {
            $(".step").hide();
            $(".step-"+nextStep).show();
        }
    </script> 

    <div class="step step-1">
        <p> Question 1 </p>
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Good!" onclick="buttonclick(2)"/> 
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Bad!" onclick="buttonclick(2)"/> 
    </div>
    <div class="step step-2">
        <p> Question 2 </p>
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Good!" onclick="buttonclick(3)"/> 
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Bad!" onclick="buttonclick(3)"/> 
    </div>
    <div class="step step-3">
        <p> Question 3 </p>
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Good!" onclick="buttonclick(1)"/> 
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Bad!" onclick="buttonclick(1)"/> 
    </div>
```

Don't forget to add the JQuery library to make it work. The function can also be replaced by .click from JQuery.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

**WORKING CODE FOR YOU** . I have added 2 level question only ... you can add more questions.

[Click for working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59rhyxba/2/)

```
 <div id="first">
    <p id ="text">How are you?</p>
    </div>


    <input type="button" id="b1" value="Good!" /> 
    <input type="button" id="b2" value="Bad!"/> 

   <script>
    $("#b1").click(function(){

        if($("#b1").val()=="Good!")
        {
       $("#text").text("Good To hear that ! Do you want to spread a smile ?");
            $("#b1").val("Yes");
             $("#b2").val("No");
        }


    });


    $("#b2").click(function(){

        if($("#b2").val()=="Bad!")
        {
       $("#text").text("Ohh Sad ! Do you want my help ?");
            $("#b1").val("Yes");
             $("#b2").val("No");
        }


    }); </script>
```

[Click for working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59rhyxba/2/)

I have done question changes for both button of question 1 only... rest you can add . Include the jquery file

Comment: @Milli  :Did you check the demo ??

Answer (score 0):

In my solution buttons' texts are changed. A decision tree of object is followed.

```
<input type="button" id="left" value="good" onclick="buttonclick(this.value)"/> 
<input type="button" id="right" value="bad" onclick="buttonclick(this.value)"/> 
<script type="text/javascript">

decision_tree = {
    'bad': {
        'some A': 'done',
        ' some B' : 'done'
    },
    'good': {
        'yes': {
            'like':'done',
            'dont like':'done'
        }, 
        'no':'done'
    }
};

left = document.getElementById("left");
right = document.getElementById("right");
st = decision_tree;
function buttonclick(v) {
    alert('you have clicked ' + v);
    if(st[v] == 'done'){
        alert('you are done with questionnaire');
        left.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        right.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else{
        console.log(st[v]);
        left.setAttribute("value",Object.keys(st[v])[0]);
        right.setAttribute("value",Object.keys(st[v])[1]);
        st = st[v];
    }

}
 </script>
```